# php comet: eating the CPU resources

Tags: php, comet

I built a website in which I used comet with php. As long I made some research and found tutorials It seems pretty easy to implement also no special requirement on a server except it will use lot of resource. Now at the moment I got notification from hosting that my script is eating the cpu resource at 90% :( I put the script off but my question is what should be best to use now? I read about node.js but also read they would need some requirement about server? Any good and easy to implement solution in this situation?

Would that be ok with VPS or dedicated servers if let say I have 2000 users each day in this comet script?

EDITED:

```
/*CLOSE THE SESSION WITH USER DATA*/
session_write_close();

// set time expire unlimited
set_time_limit(0);  

$OldPostID      = isset($_REQUEST['OldPostID']) ? intval($_REQUEST['OldPostID']) : 0;

$result_set_query_1 = $MClass->MyPostings($PageOwner); 

if (mysql_num_rows($result_set_query_1))
{
    $o = 0;
    while ($r = @mysql_fetch_array($result_set_query_1))
    {
        $PID = $r['PID'];
    }
}

$NewPostID = $PID;

while ($NewPostID <= $OldPostID)    
{
    usleep(10000); // sleep 10ms to unload the CPU
    clearstatcache();

    $result_set_query_2 = $MClass->MyPostings($PageOwner);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result_set_query_2))
    {
        $o = 0;
        while ($rs = @mysql_fetch_array($result_set_query_2))
        {
            $PID = $rs['PID'];
        }
    }

    $NewPostID = $PID;
}

// return a json array
$result_set_posts   = $MClass->GetAllMyPostings( $PageOwner, $OldPostID, 0); 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comet, per se, doesn't use a lot of resources unless instructed to- it's the script. If you were to rewrite the seemingly CPU intensive script in javascript for a Node.js server, it will most likely perform the same way.

Getting a "push" system together usually involves setting up a cloud instance-- free from Heroku, for example-- or setting a dedicated/VPS server with access to the shell.

And Node.Js is a newer, although relatively immature implementation of "push" technologies. In order to get node running, you need to install a node.Js server. And few hosts have an installation ready to go-- but it can be easily installed via a few simple shell commands.

But judging from the above scenario, few users would be able to use your app concurrently, since it is already running at 90% CPU for only one user. If the users were to use the app for a short while each session, then sure, 2000 users per day is feasible, depending how how many use it at simultaneously and when. Maybe.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated question with code I am using for comet. I used set_time_limit unlimited. I am not sure if this piece of code has the problem. Thanks

Comment: @99Points That's fine- but it still doen't say much! Where is the CPU going? Is it the MYSQL query? Are the queries searching for indexes or are they exploratory? An SQL DB with 10 rows or 10 million rows? Without exposing the guts it'll be hard to tell. HOWEVER, try the nanosleep idea below, and try limiting the sql results if it's because of the SQL.

Comment: And I'm only mentioning SQL as a possiblity since it's the biggest cause of slowdowns for scripts, besides IO-- which is also directly related to SQL usage.

Answer (score 1):

2000 user/day is a little figure, unless the typical session is 1 hour or so. Standard PHP deployments can't be used in a server-push scenario, because each request is handled with a different process.

If you don't want to purchase a dedicated server, you can try fall back to repeated polling (if, let's say, a 30 seconds delay is acceptable). However if this really helps with CPU usage depends on your actual navigation patterns, so it's just a try.

Otherwise if you can afford dedicated hardware, just use the language you are more comfortable with. Since you named Node.js, I guess you can code in Javascript, then learning Node may not be such a difficult task. There are alternatives in Python (Twisted), Java, Scala, and whatever you are proficient in. Just pick the language, and then choose the framework accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

PHP server scripts are often keept alive by running the server logic in a loop.
When I had a simmilar problem with a bcakground script running 24/7 CPU usage dropped from over 90 to below 1 percent when I added `time_nanosleep(0, 10000000);` to the end of the loop.This is NO foolproof way but it worked for me.